# Order By Clause take too much time in SQL

Tags: database, join

```
SELECT     dteRun,                 
CASE WHEN coalesce(nPriorityCode,0) <= 0 THEN 3
               ELSE nPriorityCode
               END AS nPriorityCode,
               CASE WHEN sCommand IN ('DiaryWF','XC_Reminder') THEN '*'
               ELSE ''
               END as Alert,
               sParentRef,
               nWorkflowTypeCode,
               sSubjectName,
               sDescription,
               sUniqueRef,
               sUserInfo,
               sUserInfo2   
FROM    AuroraTasksDiaryView ad
    INNER JOIN   UserAuthority
         ON UserAuthority.UserName = ad.sOwningUser
         AND ad.sOwningUser  = 'ammonsd'  AND  ad. nErrorCode = -1
         AND ad.sExcludedUser <>   ad.sOwningUser
         AND UserAuthority.FunctionCode = ad.sFunctionCode
        AND ( (UserAuthority.LowerBound <=  ad.nTaskValue
        AND UserAuthority.UpperBound >=  ad.nTaskValue)
        OR ad.sFunctionCode = 'RTS')
        AND  RowNum <= 100
        ORDER BY dteRun
```

When I omit "Order By dteRun" query runs in  milliseconds however with Order By Clause it take more than minute. Whats problem with Order By Clause ?

Comment: When you were writing your question, there was a preview of it below the text area. Worth looking at that before posting your question to make sure it's marked up correctly. Having posted it, it's also worth taking a look that things still look right. For the correct way to mark things up, refer to the **[?]** link above the text area, or indeed the quick formatting tips provided to the right of it. The more effort you put into your question, the better the answers will be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's presumably no index on the `dteRun` column. If you want to do fast `ORDER BY` on a column, it needs an index.

Comment: I have shared index on three fields in which one is dteRun (Date type), the two other are date type and number type. should i use spepate index for dteRun??

Comment: Yes. The compound index is no help here.

Comment: @ Ernest Friedman-Hill I have another query that uses composite index like dterun and tmerun in Order By Clause. Now if i use separate index for dterun and tmerun, should the efficiency in above case will be disturbed ????

Answer (score 1):

It needs an Index on columns in your `Order By` clause preferably in the same order.